# Is Google Account birth year shown?

Tags: google-account, privacy

The page ≪https://aboutme.google.com/ ≫:

[image]
(an example)

When I click on the lock icon beside "Birthday", it's this:

[image]

**Yet** when I click on the edit button, it shows:

[image]

So is the account's birth year shown or hidden to the public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody can see your "About Me" page but you. You'd need to look at your public profile.

If you go to https://profiles.google.com/me when you're logged in, it will redirect to your "public" Google profile (whether that's Google+ or not). Visit that same URL from an incognito browser tab and you'll see what other people can see.

Comment: Other than Googleplus, do you know are there other places that use /leak this information? (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115484/10579)