# Google Settings: Visible on your content & to people who interact with you

Tags: google-account, privacy, security

[Google Account ≪Gender, birthday, and more≫ settings](https://aboutme.google.com) says:

> Visible on your content & to people who interact with you

([Cf 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIXH4.png); [Cf 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUWHT.png).)

What does it refer to for accounts without Google Plus?

How's it possible that others can see the visible information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [that same page](https://aboutme.google.com/):

> Changes you make here show up across Google services like Drive, Photos, Google+ & others.

Your gender and/or birthday could be visible to anyone clicking on your "About" section from any of those services (if you've set them to Public). Blogger also sometimes has an About link for the blog's author.

Comment: Drive and Photos do not have a **public page** isn't it? I don't think there's one for Blogger too.  (Note that this is what I see when I click https://profiles.google.com/me : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUEIW.png , so I believe no one can see the information even as it is "Visible"? )

Comment: Here's a portion of a screenshot taken from a user's Blogger page (not attached to a Google+ profile) showing their gender: https://imgur.com/3Xv7yvv

Comment: Of course I'm seeing it as I'm logon to the account; The issue is does the information get seen /leaked to **others**? ¶ What's the URL of that page you ss-ed?

Comment: https://www.blogger.com/profile/02052592247572253641

Comment: I went to blogger.com and clicked "Sign In" (Top Right); It shows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/giR3m.png

Comment: You can choose which identity to use, but even with just the limited Blogger identity it will still show age/gender if you choose to make it visible.

Comment: Does "photos" have any public page too?

Comment: It doesn't appear to; viewing a public photo just shows that photo -- no album or "About Me" section.